# Import ActiveChoices script to multiple Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have different pipelines where they share the same parameters, so I need to import a file that loads the parameters from a single file.

I can't load the groovy script to my pipeline, it gives me an error and I'm stuck on how to do it.

What am I doing wrong?

**- Error:**

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface java.util.List is named ChoiceParameter
```

##### Scripts

**- Jenkinsfile**

```
    @Library('utils-choices@master') _
    
    properties(choices())
```

**- choices.groovy**

```
def call() {
    def options = [buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5')),
        parameters([
            [
                $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
                choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
                description: 'Select the ENVIRONMENT from the Dropdown List',
                filterLength: 1,
                filterable: true,
                name: 'ENVIRONMENT',
                script: [
                    $class: 'GroovyScript',
                    fallbackScript: [
                        classpath: [],
                        sandbox: true,
                        script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                    ],
                    script: [
                        classpath: [],
                        sandbox: true,
                        script: '''
                            return ['', 'UAT', 'Staging', 'Production']
                        '''.stripIndent()
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
                choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
                description: 'Select the CONTEXT from the Dropdown List',
                filterLength: 1,
                filterable: true,
                name: 'CONTEXT',
                referencedParameters: 'ENVIRONMENT',
                script: [
                    $class: 'GroovyScript',
                    fallbackScript: [
                        classpath: [],
                        sandbox: true,
                        script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                    ],
                    script: [
                        classpath: [],
                        sandbox: true,
                        script: '''
                            if (ENVIRONMENT == 'Production') {
                                return ['', 'GE', 'FR', 'PO', 'HG']
                            } else if (ENVIRONMENT == 'UAT') {
                                return ['', 'GE', 'FR', '']
                            } else if (ENVIRONMENT == 'Staging') {
                                return ['', 'FR']
                            } else {
                                return ['Select ENVIRONMENT']
                            }
                        '''.stripIndent()
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ])
    ]
    return options
}
return this
```

Comment: What if you use `List options = ...` or `return [ buildDiscarder(...), parameters(...) ]` directly?

Comment: I tried both but it gives the same error

Comment: What if you use [`$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/ChoiceParameterDefinition.html) instead?

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface java.util.List is named ChoiceParameterDefinition

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Just need to add a [] into choices.groovy